# Error sql adding double values on mysql database

Tags: mysql

Error

SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE `gts` ADD `latitude` DOUBLE( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
ADD `longitude` DOUBLE( 10 ) NOT NULL
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') NOT NULL,  ADD `longitude` DOUBLE(10) NOT NULL' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like.

```
ALTER TABLE gts ADD latitude DOUBLE(10,0 ) NOT NULL , ADD longitude DOUBLE(10,0) NOT NULL
```

Comment: (10,0) will not allow for decimal points and you forgot about the second double field.

Answer (score 0):

double values need 2 parameters.

`DOUBLE(10,2)` means 10 in size, 2 after the "," (decimal places).

read more here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html

Answer (score 0):

Double should have 2 parameters:

```
ALTER TABLE `gts` ADD `latitude` DOUBLE( 10,0 ) NOT NULL ,ADD `longitude` DOUBLE( 10 ) NOT NULL
```

Please refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/floating-point-types.html